# Perspective origin and vanishing points

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand how `perspective-origin` affects vanishing points. I understand that the red square should vanish into the absolute center, but it appears to vanish towards the center-right instead. The lines would converge towards the center-right. I know I'm misunderstanding this somehow, but I don't know what I'm missing. I've read through whatever documentation I could find on this.

```css
.container {
  background: gray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  perspective: 50px;
  perspective-origin: center center;
}

.contained {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(45deg);
  transform-origin: center left;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div class="contained"></div></div>
```

Comment: *but it appears to vanish towards the center-right* --> you mean center-left?

Comment: To me, it looks like it gets smaller towards the center-right. center-left is the transform-origin, not the perspective origin.

Comment: well, I am not sure to understand your confusion but it seems your confusing between the transformation and the perspective. Imagine your self opening a window while looking at its center. This is exactly what is happning here.